# How can I select and style an asterisk in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I would need to set a specific color to a special character.

Specifically, I would like to set the asterisk `*` in a `<div>` to color `red`, without intervening directly in the `<div>`.

Online I found this project, which actually goes to set a background color to a character, however if I adapt the script to the * symbol it doesn't work.

Example output:

[image: Desired result]

```
$("p").highlight("*","highlight");
```

```js
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {    
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");

    return this.each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + matched + "</span>";});
    });
};

$("p").highlight("*","highlight");
```

```css
span.highlight{
   background:#F60;
    padding:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFF;
}

p{
   font-family:Verdana;   
}
```

```html
<p>
    Let's *go Zapata let's do it for the revolution, Zapatistas*!!!   
</p>
```

If instead of `Z` I put the asterisk `*` the script doesn't work. Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the asterisk, as it also has significance in regex. Use `\\*`:

**Edit:** As suggested by @DBS, better to add this check for escaping in the highlight function itself. Code is modified.

```js
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(str, className) {
  var escapeRegExp = function(string) {
    return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
  }
  var regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(str), "gi");

  return this.each(function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {
      return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + matched + "</span>";
    });
  });
};

$("p").highlight("*", "highlight");
$("label").highlight("*", "highlight");
```

```css
span.highlight {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #F60;
}

p {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #F60;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Let's *go Zapata let's do it for the revolution, Zapatistas*!!!
</p>

<label for="txt">Email* </label>
<input placeholder="Email*" type="text" id="txt"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to enter the code but a strange thing happens. If I put everything in a `<div>` it works without problems, however I can't apply the script to the fields of the email form

[image]

Comment: You can add it to labels, but for placeholders it will not work since it is a pseudo element. You'll need to apply the style to the `::placeholder` selector entirely. Check edits in my answer

Comment: Thank you!  @Anurag Srivastava

Comment: Glad to help...keep coding!